# c# Many Parent forms one child

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have Parent_1, Parent_2, Parent_3 and etc. and have one Child form

in Parent_1, Parent_2, Parent_3 ...  I have:

```
private string strText;
public string pubText { 
get { return strText; } 
set { strText = value; } }
```

on button:

```
private void btbutton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var form = new fChild(this);
            form.ShowDialog();
        }
```

in child form I have the code:

```
private Parent_1 logicalParent;
public fChild(Parent_1 parent)
{
     InitializeComponent();
     logicalParent = parent;
     this.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(child_FormClosed);
}
```

and

```
void child_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
     logicalParent.pubText = this.textBox1.Text;
}
```

This works only for 1 parent form, How Can I use this for other Parent forms???
Please Help

Comment: What is the closest analogy to said hierarchy? `MessageBox` dialog? Then you shouldn't pass `Parent_1` type into child, but some base type of all parents. Perhaps `Form` will do, unless you have to cast much, then consider using interface/base type.

Comment: Use `private Parent_1 logicalParent;` instead of `private Form logicalParent;` and to set property use GetType() and set value ! or you can use a common interface for all parent forms and keep property of `pubText ` in interface !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a common interface for the three parent forms:

```
public interface IParentForm
{
    string PubText {get; set;}
}

public class Parent_1 : Form, IParentForm
{
    public string PubText
    {
         get { return this.pubText; }
         set { this.pubText = value; }
    }
}

//same for Parent_2 and 3
```

then in your child form declare `logicalParent` to be of type `IParentForm`, and change the constructor of the child form to be `public fChild(IParentForm parent)`

Comment: it would be good to include the part with the child constructor. Since this is the reason, why OP is asking this question

Comment: Can you tell me  - var form = new fChild(); inside "()"

Comment: @DavidMamulashvili you should still be able to use `var form = new fChild(this)` if your parent form implements `IParentForm`

Answer (score 1):

At the button click do the following:

```
  private void btbutton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var form = new fChild(this); // this is not more needed
        form.ShowDialog();
        pubText = form.pubText;
    }
```

Comment: This works only for one parent. And I want get string from Child to Parent